# Converting Wiki Markup to Plain Text

Tags: php, mediawiki, pear, markup, text-processing

Using  [Pear Wiki package](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Wiki_Mediawiki/redirected), I tried using following code to convert some media wiki to plain text, but it does not work as expected. What is wrong with it?

```
require_once "Text/Wiki/Mediawiki.php";
$p=new Text_Wiki_Mediawiki();

echo $p->transform('==a title==[[ a link]]','plain');

// I expect "a title a link" but it returns: "==a title==[[ a link]]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, this package built path to class dynamically and throw no exception. In addition to PEAR Text_Mediawiki package you should also get core PEAR packages and add its path to `include_path`.

Answer (score 0):

Header declarations in the media wiki markup have to be on separate lines, so the following will work:

```
<?php
require_once "Text/Wiki/Mediawiki.php";
$p=new Text_Wiki_Mediawiki();

echo $p->transform("==a title==\n[[ a link]]","plain");
```